# Can't display UIAlert from SLComposeViewController

Tags: swift, share, uialertcontroller, slcomposeviewcontroller

I'm using a Share Extension to upload an article object to Firebase. That works fine, but I can't get the Success Alert to show up without getting a "modifying autolayout engine from background thread" error.

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/hferrone/b2837525c50342b92fcb)

Answer (score 0):

Then your alert code is being called from a background thread.  Instead do something like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // put your UIAlertController code in this completion block
}
```